# Is there a way of getting an item from a list by searching its position in python

Tags: python, indexing

If I have a list of items e.g words=['Hi','I'm','a','computer']. Is there any way I can get the item with the index so it would look something like this...

Input:

> print(words.index(2))

Output:

> I'm

So in conclusion i am looking for a way to reverse the index() function and use the index to search an object rather than an object to find the index.

Comment: `words[1]` gives `I'm` ?

Comment: Go [read a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) or something. This operation is literally the most fundamental thing you can do with a list. Reading a tutorial will give you the basics you need a lot faster than asking questions for all of them.

Comment: ['Hi','I'm','a','computer'] should be ['Hi','I\'m','a','computer'] if you want only to use single quotes

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the following syntax to access a certain element of your list:

```
words[1]
```

Output:

```
I'm
```

Note that the index starts with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Lists in python are like arrays in Java, C or other languages. Just index them.

```
words[1]
```